# JavaScript onchange value, changes on every input

Tags: jquery

Im trying to work with Bootstrap Modal Form.
What I want to achive is when user open modal with dynamicaly generated form with filled inputs, and when user wants to change some values then email is going to be sent with new values.

Im using:

```
        let emlTitle = $('#queryEmailTitle');        
        $(document).on('change', emlTitle, function(titleVal) {
            
            var emlProofTitle = titleVal.target.value;
       
            $('#queryEmailTitle').val(emlProofTitle);

        });

        let emlBody = $('#queryEmailBody');
        $(document).on('change', emlBody, function(bodyVal) {
            
            var emlProofBody = bodyVal.target.value;

            $('#queryEmailBody').val(emlProofBody);

        });
```

But the problem is that when i change value of one input, for example #queryEmailTitle, then #queryEmailBody gets same value as new value #queryEmailTitle

Cane any one show me what Im doing wrong?

Thanks in adcance.

Comment: The second parameter must be a *string*, not a jquery object:  `$(document).on('change', "#queryEmailBody",`

Answer (score 1):

As per the jQuery documentation you are passing wrong parameters to **.on** function.

```
    let emlBody = $('#queryEmailBody');
    $(document).on('change', emlBody, function(bodyVal) {
        
        var emlProofBody = bodyVal.target.value;

        $('#queryEmailBody').val(emlProofBody);

    });
```

Refer https://api.jquery.com/on/

Rather than having 2 **.on** event listeners you could it with one function.

```
    $(document).on('change', function(event) {
        
        var val= event.target.value;

        if (event.target.id === 'queryEmailTitle') {
            $('#queryEmailTitle').val(val);
        }
        else if (event.target.id === 'queryEmailBody') {
           $('#queryEmailBody').val(val);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Combing two separate events into one is a style issue.  To me, it's much more confusing and prone to errors.  It might be ok here, with just a 1 liner, but generally combining events with multiple lines of code just makes one large switch/spaghetti event handler.  All OP needs to do is change to `$(document).on('change', "#queryEmailBody",`

Answer (score 1):

From jquery's [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
>
> **selector**
> Type: `String`
> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

The second argument to `.on` needs to be a string; you're passing a jquery object.

Giving:

```
$(document).on('change', "#queryEmailTitle", function(titleVal) {
```

Note that IDs must be unique, so if you have an `queryEmailTitle` on your page and another one on the dialog, you're likely to have issues.